# How do I get data to both UserID view and Normal view in Google Analytics

Tags: events, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Using GMP, I'm firing events from my back-end system to GA, with an associated UserID. Essentially I'm measuring conversions on lead forms as the leads are manually processed and registered in the back-end system and either generate sales, or don't.

The events I'm firing are visible in a UserID view, but not on my normal views. I understand that this is because I'm assigning a UserID when I fire the event. My question is: What is the best way to get these events to show up in my normal views **as well**? I'd like the data in both views, for different purposes. Should I fire double events, one with and one without the UserID?

The current package looks like this:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?
v=1&
t=event&
tid=[GA_TRACKING_ID]&
uid=[USER_ID]&
ec=application&
ea=submit&
el=[APPLICATION_ID]&
ev=[OUR_ASSIGNED_VALUE]&
cd1=submit
```

Any suggestions are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass it as custom dimension with user scope.

Comment: Thanks Michele!

I've added an example of our event.

Just to make sure I understand, do you mean I should push the USER_ID as cd2 (for example) as well as the UID parameter, or should I replace the UID parameter with a cd2?

Comment: You have to send USER_ID as cd2 but is VERY important that you use cid too, otherwise you won't see hits in your normal view.